Why is Special Relativity preferred over Lorentz Ether Theory?
Special Relativity and Lorentz Ether Theory make the same predictions, so they cannot be experimentally differentiated. (Are Lorentz aether theory and special relativity fully equivalent?). As such, distinctions between them are conceptual. From what I understand, the key distinction between the two theories are how they assume light moves. In Special Relativity, it is assumed that the two-way speed of light is constant for all observers. In Lorentz Ether Theory, it is assumed that the speed of light moves at a constant speed through some universal ether frame. Most of the arguments I've seen against Lorentz Ether Theory are that it is more conceptually complicated because of the inclusion of this universal ether frame, but from this Lorentz Ether Theory doesn't need the constant two-way speed of light assumption. Neither theory seems to make fewer assumptions than the other. Lorentz Ether Theory also gives (in my opinion) much more satisfying explanations of the mechanics behind time dilation and length contraction.
Given the similarity of the two theories, why is Special Relativity preferred? Also, as far as I know Lorentz Ether Theory has not be analogously extended to something like General Relativity or applied to Quantum Field Theory. Are there fundamental issues with doing this, or has this not been attempted?

This question is similar to: Are Lorentz aether theory and special relativity fully equivalent?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

While the duplicate is related, the OP isn't asking if the two theories are equivalent, but rather why one is chosen over the other. I see it discussed in the duplicate, but it's not the focus of the question or any of the answers

The "mechanism" proposed by LET for time dilation and length contraction might make sense for electromagnetic interactions, but it's difficult to extend to gravitational or nuclear interactions. The usual geometric interpretation of special relativity explains these phenomena in a simple way which applies to everything and moreover naturally extends to a relativistic theory of gravity (general relativity).

@BioPhysicist :  The duplicate establishes that the theories are equivalent, which means there is no reason other than personal preference to prefer one over the other, which answers this question.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor

@EricSmith, the geometric (Einsteinian) approach quantifies gravitational effects, but it doesn't "explain" them in any meaningful sense (it postulates that gravity is simply fundamental and sui generis, so doesn't need any further explanation), and implicitly it also falls back onto an aether-like concept in that it attributes gravitational properties to areas of otherwise empty space. Einstein himself explicitly acknowledged these points. (1/3)

In terms of simplicity, GR on its own may be a relatively simple theory compared to any possible Lorentzian explanation, but the whole body of prevailing physical theory consists of irreconcilable theories (like GR and QM), which each adopt as-yet unreconciled concepts within them, so it's far to soon to say that things are being explained in the simplest way possible. (2/3)

Finally, I'd speculate that the Lorentzian explanation of certain effects gravitational fields (such as slowed clocks), would probably follow the same explanation as experimentally verified phenomenon of slowed propagation speeds in other explicit mediums which have a different refractive index than free space. Since the Lorentzian approach doesn't assume an isotropic speed of light axiomatically, these variances in light speed don't pose conceptual challenges. (3/3)

About the question of choosing between special relativity and Lorentz Ether theory.
Historically there have been cases with a parallel to that question.
I will first describe one such parallel case, and then I will return to special relavitity.

By the 1930's there was sufficient data from cloud chamber observations that there was something odd with beta decay. With all other forms of decay there was corroboration of conservation of energy, but with beta decay this was not the case.
Historians of science describe that Niels Bohr proposed to relinquish the principle of conservation of energy.
Another proposal was a theory of beta decay in which the missing energy is carried off by an a particle that is invisible to any detection.
In cloud chambers it is charged particles that trigger condensation. By the 1930's time the existence of the neutron was known. By itself a neutron does not trigger condensation in a cloud chamber, but sooner or later the neutron collides with something, in that collision event multiple particles are created, and from the trails of those particles the transient presense of a neutron can be inferred. Even if the probablity of a neutron interaction is low, as long as that probability is non-zero a sufficiently large experiment will eventually generate enough events to get to statistically significant numbers.
So OK, let's say we propose a small neutral particle, and we attribute to it a probability of interacting with other matter far smaller than neutrons.
As the experiments were refined no candidates for the 'little neutral particle' were encountered;  the existence of the 'little neutral particle' seemed ever less plausible.

To propose a particle that is created in a decay event and subsequently never ever interacts with any other matter, that seems silly.
On a philosophic level: to propose the existence of a particle that is inherently undetectable: well, if you do that you lose more than you gain. Such a theory isn't ever going to increase your understanding of the physical world.

Now, in the case of the neutrino: eventually the existence of neutrino's was confirmed in the 1950'; the Cowan-Reines neutrino experiment. Neutrino's have an exceedingly low probability of interaction with other particles.
My point is: as long as the purported neutrino particle remained undetected the case against the neutrino particle was strong.



Returning to special relativity:
Lorentz Ether theory requires simultaneous supposition of the following: the existence of a Lorentz Ether, and the existence of a set of physical properties such that the Lorentz Ether is undetectable.
I submit:
To propose a theory with an entity (Lorentz Ether) that is inherently undetectable, such a theory isn't ever going to increase your knowledge of the physical world.


For me that is the reason for preferring the special relativity interpretation over the Lorentz Ether interpretation.

The current dominant interpretation of special relativity isn't actually Einstein's original formulation, but rather Minkowski's geometrical formulation in terms of spacetime. This has a number of conceptual advantages over Lorentz ether theory. As you point out yourself, the geometric interpretation extends naturally to gravity (general relativity) and to quantum field theory. The geometric explanation of time dilation and length contraction is simple, applies to all interactions (not just ones based on electromagnetism), and also explains gravitational time dilation. It also doesn't require hypothesizing an unobservable ether.
The vast majority of working physicists are quite content with the geometric interpretation, and the success of its extension to general relativity means there's very little incentive to pursue an ether based theory of gravity or of QFT.

There is a wide range of interpretations. I am committed to the concept of Minkowski spacetime, but I meticulously avoid geometric interpretation. It may be that such a point of view appears self-contradictory to you. That is what may happen when there are multiple interpretations in circulation. Diffierent interpretations may not be mutually intelligible

@Cleonis Minkowski spacetime is the local representation of the geometric model. The only "problem" with the geometric model, if you want, is that it gives us the wrong ontology of time, but you won't do better in Lorentz ether models, either. If anything you are getting further and further away from real physics.

When you say "very little", can you be more specific about precisely what that entails?  Or did you really mean "no".

@FlatterMann what do you mean by "the wrong ontology of time"?

@m4r35n357 Time is that which the clocks show. Clocks are physical systems with a local energy reservoir that disperse this energy evenly over all of spacetime. When we are talking about time we are really talking about the energy flow of clocks. That is the reason why time is not really a geometric quantity and one can't talk about only "one time". There are infinitely many possible energy reservoirs and that is why there can be infinitely many clocks.

@FlatterMann Hmm, never heard of that viewpoint - is it mainstream - what is it called?

@m4r35n357 What did you never hear about? What a clock is in terms of actual physics? To the theorists it rarely matters. They are abstracting the physical details away, however to the experimental physicists it's very important and it enters theory in a very unsettling way once you start thinking about quantum gravity and Planck scale physics. At that level you can't avoid thinking about the physical mechanism of time keeping any longer.

@FlatterMann "energy flow of clocks" sounds like stoner talk to me.  How can "energy" be localized into a concept (a clock)?  OK if it is to do with quantum gravitation I shall wait for a finished theory.

@FlatterMann I think I need to use more precise words. I am committed to regarding the invariance of the spacetime interval as fundamental (whereas in an LET that invariance is interpreted as a downstream consequence). I also regard space and time as intrinsically distinct. Example of difference. When two measuring rods are separated and later rejoined they are the same length again; length contraction reverts, regardless of history. As we know: in the case where clocks travel along paths of different spatial length difference in amount of elapsed proper time accumulates.

@m4r35n357 Every clock has an energy storage device like a battery or a spring (or just a weight on a string). What about that is not obvious to you?

@Cleonis A spacetime interval is a theoretical abstract. We can't measure it without a physical system that includes clocks and rulers of some sort.

@FlatterMann Why is it not obvious to you that a physical clock is part of the physical world (I guess you could say a sundial is the most "inefficient" clock there is!).  A theoretical clock has no energy.  Relativistic calculations never include any energy associated with clocks (which clocks anyway?).

@m4r35n357 I will be happy to agree with you as soon as you show me a clock that doesn't need energy. Until then I will apply the scientific method and only talk about things that are actually observable in this universe.

@FlatterMann I already have.  Think about the clocks in Einstein's train/station experiment, and account for the energy flow of the clocks there if you can.  All rulers have mass too, but not the ones in relativity ;)

@m4r35n357 I will be happy to agree with you as soon as you show me a massless ruler. You don't have to go to special relativity for that problem, to begin with. It already exists in form of Newton's first law. You need a massive body to define a rest system. Nothing changes about that in special relativity.

. . . and we come back to Occam's Razor.  Rulers have no mass and clocks have no energy because they are not part of any physical system.  They are purely conceptual, like unicorns.  Anyway we are now going in circles . . .


Lorentz Ether Theory also gives (in my opinion) much more satisfying
explanations of the mechanics behind time dilation and length
contraction.

I agree. For example, lets say using LET theory, that A is rest with the Ether and B is moving relative to the Ether. B length contracts due to his motion relative to the Ether. B really physically contracts. because of B's motion relative to the Ether his rulers length contract and his clocks run slower and by his measurements, A appears to be length contracted. In SR it the motion relative to A that 'causes' the length contraction of B and if there is a third observer C moving relative to both A and B, then the length contraction of B from C's point of view is caused by B's motion relative to C. If C is not a huge gravitational body, then the motion of B relative to C should have no physical effect on B, so the fact that B length contracts by a factor that is function of B's velocity relative to C is just a mathematical outcome, not a physical effect. In SR there is no common cause for the length contraction and it appears to be an phantom property - just an appearance. I am convinced this is why many people even here on this forum are confused by the Ehrenfest paradox, Bell's rocket paradox and the twins' paradox, because they cannot accept the physical reality of length contraction and time dilation.
Let's examine the twins' paradox. Lets say The earth is stationary and twin B flies away and returns later. Since B has been moving relative to the Ether and A has not there is no no question that B should have aged the least. Let's reverse the situation. If the Earth is initially moving relative to the Ether, and B is at rest relative to the Ether, then the twin on Earth is initially aging slower. In order for B to return to the Earth, B has to return to Earth faster than A was initially moving away from B. B has on average the highest velocity relative to the Ether and B obviously ages the least. There is no question of anyone getting confused and saying the situation is symmetrical and the twins should age the same amount.
let's analyse Bell's rocket paradox using LET. Let's say the rockets are initially at rest with the Ether. if there is a string connecting the rockets and they accelerate in such a way that the distance between them remains constant relative to an observer at rest in the initial reference frame, then the connecting string connecting the two rockets must be length contracting because it is moving relative to the ether and since the rockets maintain a constant separation, the string must be getting stretched and eventually break. If LET had been the accepted interpretation, Bell's rocket paradox would not exist. When Bell announced the connecting string must break it would not have been controversial. Everyone would have just said "of course it does!" Where's the paradox?" That is exactly what LET predicts! If LET had been accepted, there probably would have been no confusion and no relativistic paradoxes. Relativity would have been much easier to understand, but perhaps that is boring. We would not have thousands of book, blogs and videos about the mysteries of relativity and perhaps that is why the SR interpretation is better because it creates a whole industry, based on confusion. The case against LET is that the Ether is undetectable. It is only logically there. The same could be said for Dark matter. Scientists argue it is logically there, but they have ever been able to determine what is made of or directly detect it. When we talk about the expanding universe  and people ask what is expanding, the answer is 'space' which is made of nothing. In the LET interpretation we could argue that it is the Ether that is expanding. Objects far away from us are moving at appar3ently relativistic speeds, but they do not experience time dilation due to their relative motion to us, because they are at rest with the local Ether. Superluminal recession velocities are not a problem because its not the galaxies that are receding superluminally, but the ether.  In "The river model of black holes" by Andrew J. S. Hamilton and Jason P. Lisle  published in the American Journal of Physics)  and "the river model of space" by S. Braeck, O. Gron, spacetime is described as flowing into the the black hole with a velocity of c at the event horizon and a velocity greater than c below the event horizon. If we ask what exactly is flowing, the Ether is an obvious candidate.

But see problems with the river model as a conceptualization of black holes. In general it is problematic to reify particular coordinate choices, which seems to be what you are aiming for.

Can you tell me how I measure this ether? What experiment do I have to perform that gives me exactly the same motion from ALL observers?

@FlatterMann same motion of what?

I don't see how this answers the question

The ether. It is supposed to be a singleton, isn't it? How do I measure my relative motion to it?

Nice answer (+1) Could you elaborate why "using LET theory, A is rest with the Ether and B is moving relative to the Ether, then B's length contracts due to his motion relative to the Ether. B really physically contracts", please? So if a sphere is travelling relative to the Ether, does it physically become egg-shaped? Then its individual atoms and electrons also become elongated... Why does travelling across the ether cause an atom to become elongated?

@james When Lorentz formulated his theory, he considered the length contraction to be real even down to the atomic level. The length contraction is due to motion relative to the ether, which to me makes a lot more sense than saying an object contracts due to its motion relative to me the observer. How does the mass of my body affect the length of a distant rocket. (I know i have put on on a bit of weight, but...). Not only is the distant rocket length contracting relative to me in SR, but it also simultaneously length contracting to a different extent relative to other observers.

@james The traditional SR interpretation leads people to conclude that length contraction is not real. However, the fact that a light signals return simultaneously from the two arms of a MMX type device requires length contraction to explain it. To me, it is intellectually dishonest to explain to students that the reason light returns simultaneously in that experiment is because one of the arms length contracts and at the same time claim length contraction is not real. If length contraction is a not a real physical effect, then we need another explanation for the null result of the MMX.

@KDP thank you. I am real curious as to what was Lorentz's original argument, how did he conclude that a spherical hydrogen atom moving through the ether would become elongated? What was the ether actually made of according to Lorentz? (I am ignorant of much physics history)

Probably best to try and google an original paper by Lorentz.  I am not sure if Lorentz stated what the Ether was made of and it is not reasonable to expect that. It is enough to say what its properties are. For example, physicists think there is dark matter causing additional gravitation. They do not know what dark matter is made of, despite extensive efforts made over the last 50 years to find out. They simply say what properties dark matter has. It interacts gravitationally but interacts very weakly electromagnetically. and does not clump together to form stars or black holes.
